# How can I reach the island at the end of the forest in candy box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

I keep trying to get through the forest but I still cannot reach the small island at the end of the forest. How can I get to the island?

Comment: You reach the castle entrance through the woods, and not the island.

Comment: But problem is, I want to get to the island to see the Cyclops and not go to the castle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You reach the small island via the pier.

You unlock the pier once you have finished the cave.

[image: Circled pier]

Then click in "Go to the lighthouse by boat"

[image: Click "Go to the lighthouse by boat"]

Comment: But I still cannot see the pier, eventhough I already battled through the forest countless of times. Is there any other way to reach the pier, instead through the forest?

Comment: @poison123 The pier is unlocked after you travel through the caves.  Unless you've found a bug, you should be able to go there by clicking the pier.

Comment: I keep reaching the big forest, I can't seem to get to the pier, yet.

Comment: @poison123 And clicking on the pier still doesn't do anything?

Comment: No, problem is, I've been walking round' the caves for a long time now and it still says "you finally reached the cave's exit, you can see a big forest outside of here"

Comment: @poison123 Which takes you to the world map. Once you've done that, you can click on the pier to go there.

Comment: nope...done that, and I still can't see the pier, it just doesn't appear in the world map... :(

Comment: Do I need to travel on a specific path so that I can reach the pier?

Comment: @poison123 No. Once you've completed the caves, you should be able to travel there by clicking on either the pier or the boat. If you can't, I can only assume it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks, it probably is a bug anyway...is it important to get to the pier?

Comment: @poison123 Yes, it's required to complete the game.

Comment: so, if it is a bug, how can I still finish the game? (because I heard there's a lot of things there) Can I ask someone to fix the system or something?

Comment: @poison123 Can you edit your text save into your question? I want to see if this is a bug with your save.

Comment: sorry, it's too long, what should I do?

Comment: @poison123 If you find a way to send me the save let me know. If not, I can only assume it's a bug and you will have to restart.

Comment: I have to agree with Studoku, I believe it's a bug. All you have to do is get through the caves, then you'll be able to click on the pier or the boat to get to the pier. Then you can click on 'Go to the lighthouse by boat' and you'll get to the island with the lighthouse and the cyclops.